# Draw a handful of random vectors iid. Is projecting one onto the handful essentially the same as projecting one onto another?

Tags: statistics, lie-groups, projection, random-matrices, geometric-probability

Fix some distribution $D$ over the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^n$.
For $k<n$ and $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k \overset{iid}\sim D$, call $X=[x_1,\dots,x_k]$ and identify the projection onto $\operatorname{range} X$ as $P_X = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$. I am interested in minimizing $E\left[\|P_X x_0\|^2\right]$ among distributions $D$ from some collection $\mathcal{D}$.

Examples: If $D$ is concentrated at a unit vector then $E\left[\|P_X x_0\|^2\right]=1$.
On the other hand, if $D$ has randomness then $P_X$ may throw away some of $x_0$.

Finally the question: given the iid aspect, is it enough to assume $k=1$?
This would allow me to work with a hopefully simpler quantity, minimizing $E\left[\|x_0'x_1\|^2\right]$.

Comment: After you choose one vector, you can reduce the problem to a problem over $k-1$ points over a modified distribution plus the one term case. If you can prove that the $k=1$ case is $1/n$, then induction gives you $k/n$

Comment: More conditions are needed on the family $\mathcal{D}$.
 Say $n,k$ are huge and $\mathcal{D}$ contains two distributions: $${}$$ 
(1) unit vectors unformly chosen from within some $k/10^6$-dimensional subspace, or $${}$$ 
(2) unit vectors are highly correlated symmetrically around a point on the complex unit $n$-sphere. $${}$$
Now "$\min E[x_0'x_1]$" wants the first distribution, but "$\min E[P_Xx_0]$" wants the second.